# Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: классы, указатели, c++, visual-c++

Почему компилятор ругается при возвращении указателя на объект внутреннего класса в методе внешнего? Допустим, мы имеем вот такой класс-шаблон:

```
template <class T> class BST {
    int sizeBST;
    int fun_count;
  private:
    class node {
      public:
        int key;
        T data;
        int bal;
        node *left, *right;
        node(int, T);
        ~node();
    } *head;

  public:BST();
    node *min(node *);
}
```

Так вот, после описания метода node *min(node*) и компиляции, компилятор ругается, типо `error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'.`
примерное описание метода:

```
template <class T> node * BST <T>::min(node * elem)
{
    if (elem != NULL) {
        while (1) {
            if (elem->left != NULL)
                elem = elem->left;
            else
                return elem;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
};
```

Метод должен найти минимальный узел по ключу в дереве от входящего указателя и возвратить указатель на найденный или NULL, если такого нет. В чем дело?

Компилятор VC++.

Comment: Метод должен найти минимальный узел по ключу в дереве от входящего указателя и возвратить указатель на найденный или NULL если такого нет.

Comment: И? поставил, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Это весь кусок? И полностью сообщение компилятора, без "типо", с номером строки. У меня этот кусок компилируется нормально. g++ v4.6.3

Comment: добавил описание в вопросе

Comment: Добавил второй кусок. На его первую строчку компилятор ответственно заявляет:

     e.c++:19:22: ошибка: «node» не является именем типа

Номер строк могут быть смещены, я по нему indent'ом прошёлся.

Comment: окей... а решение то какое?

Comment: @Djonny: (закончился лимит комментариев к вопросу, отвечаю здесь) да, можно сделать публичный метод, который вызывает приватный, но это не поможет: какой вы поставите тип возвращаемого значения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хочется определить эту функцию вне определения класса, надо так:

```
template <class T> typename BST<T>::node * BST<T>::min (node* elem) {
   ........
}
```

1. Тип node объявлен внутри шаблона BST, поэтому для работы с ним вне тела класса надо писать, что он к нему относится, и не просто к нему, а к конкретному его инстанцированному экземпляру
2. Поскольку BST<T> здесь указывается без конкретных шаблонных аргументов, при обращении к его внутренним типам надо указывать, что это именно типы, а не какие-то статические члены. Этому служит ключевое слово `typename`
3. Все это не нужно указывать во второй раз (в списке аргументов функции), поскольку указывается, что функция относится к такому-то пространству имен и по правилу какого-то там мужика (не помню его имени) это пространство начинает использоваться.

Только проблема остается: как использовать эту функцию для внешних пользователей, если возвращаемый тип - приватный. Только либо для внутренних нужд (и тогда ее лучше сделать приватной), либо для дружественных функций и классов. Продумайте этот момент.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Спасибо Вам огромное! Если бы не ваш ответ я бы никогда не узнал о таких тонкостях!=) Ну может быть узнал, но не скоро=)

Answer (score 3):

А как класс может выдать наружу указатель на экземпляр приватного внутреннего класса? Это раз.

Во-вторых, `min` кое-где объявлен как макрос: `#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))` или улучшенные варианты, это может "сбить" компиляцию.

---

Я попробовал ваш код на Visual Studio.

В общем, всё ещё проще: вы забыли точку с запятой в конце объявления класса.

Comment: 2-учту, а 1-е внутренний класс все равно останется в привате, такова задумка, но как тогда сделать, что бы он мог выдавать?

Comment: @Djonny: сразу встречный вопрос -- а как им будут пользоваться? от этого всё зависит.

Comment: так все просто, любые действия с внутренним классом будут реализованы через  открытые методы.

Comment: @Djonny: посмотрите на обновление в ответе :)

Comment: @Djonny: тогда вам придётся перевести этот класс в public, иначе к нему никто не сможет доступиться.

Comment: а класс protected мне поможет выйти из ситуации?

Comment: не-а, если только не переведёте и метод `min` в protected

Comment: т.е. я могу сделать и такой геморой - метод min поместить в private  а в public поместить новый метод в котором будет осуществляться вызов метода min?=)

Answer (score 0):

Ежели я не прав, пусть знатоки этого це-два-креста меня поправят (я в их число не вхожу)

```
template < class T > class BST {
    int sizeBST;
    int fun_count;
 private:
    class node {
 public:
        int key;
        T data;
        int bal;
        node *left, *right;
        node(int, T);
        ~node();
    } *head;

 public:BST();
    node *min(node * elem) {
        if (elem != NULL) {
            while (1) {
                if (elem->left != NULL)
                    elem = elem->left;
                else
                    return elem;
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    };
};
```

Comment: Решение по-пролетарски: дешево и без изысков.